# Patch Operation Causes Connection to be forcibly closed

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am using the patch operation to create or if it already exists update a property on a document in a Cosmos DB Container. When the property name is made up of 12 or more numbers the the following exception the thrown.

```
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Here is my code

```
var _endpointUri = "https://localhost:8081/";
var _primaryKey = "primary key";


using CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(_endpointUri, _primaryKey);
var database = client.GetDatabase("Orders");
var container = database.GetContainer("Batches");


List<PatchOperation> operations = new()
        {
            PatchOperation.Set($"/batches/111122223333", DateTime.Now),
        };

ItemResponse<BatchIndexDocument> r = await container.PatchItemAsync<BatchIndexDocument>(
      id: "10001",
      partitionKey: new PartitionKey("10001"),
      patchOperations: operations,
      requestOptions: opt
  );
```

if you replace the number with letters then the operation completes without erroring

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `/batches/111122223333` can either mean that there is a property `111122223333` or that you are setting the item in the array `batches` with index `111122223333`, because of the schema-less nature of JSON.

When you add a letter, because it is no longer a full number, it cannot be an index of an array, but rather a property.

When interpreted as the index, the operation might be timing out attempting to locate the position in the index treating `batches` as an array. Ideally this scenario is something you want to do a [support request](https://aka.ms/azure-support).

Comment: I appreciate your prompt and helpful reply to my inquiry. For now, I suspect the simple solution is to include a letter so that the property name is not interpreted as an index.